# Error occurred while i am trying to run my sample app on ios simulator

Tags: ios, linker-errors

The unexpected error that i can't understand is as below:

```
    "_CGAffineTransformIdentity", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextAddPath", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextFillPath", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetGrayStrokeColor", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetLineJoin", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetShadowWithColor", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetTextMatrix", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextSetTextPosition", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGPathAddRect", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGPathCreateMutable", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGRectContainsPoint", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGRectGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGRectInset", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGRectZero", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CGSizeZero", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFontCreateCopyWithAttributes", referenced from:
      ___NSAttributedStringByScalingFontSize_block_invoke in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFontCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      _NSAttributedStringAttributesFromLabel in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFontGetSize", referenced from:
      ___NSAttributedStringByScalingFontSize_block_invoke in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFontGetUnderlineThickness", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFrameGetLineOrigins", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFrameGetLines", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawBackground:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFramesetterCreateFrame", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel characterIndexAtPoint:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel framesetter] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
      -[TTTAttributedLabel sizeThatFits:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineCreateTruncatedLine", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineCreateWithAttributedString", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
  "_CTLineDraw", referenced from:
      -[TTTAttributedLabel drawFramesetter:attributedString:textRange:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **CoreText** and **CoreGraphics** framework to your app.